# I can not increase Headphone volume from alsamixer

Tags: command-line

I can not increase Headphone volume from alsamixer

[image: alsamixer]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've already covered this part!  but ...just in case....
I just opened alsamixer myself on a terminal and I see that I cannot control my headphone volume from there either. However, I don't have my headphones plugged in.  That would correct the situation, plugging them in.  Obvious, maybe not.  Your welcome.